# My extension can only be enabled in the chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-store

After I install my extension it doesn't get activated, so I go to my downloaded extension page, it says that my extension is corrupted. I hit the repair button but I just get console errors.

[image]

However, my extension works if I hit enable on the chrome web store...

[image]

My extension works perfectly after I hit the "enable this item" button in the chrome web store. However, I can't enable it once I'm in my downloaded chrome extensions.  Is my chrome extension broken or is it a bug in chrome. If it is a bug, where can I submit it?

Comment: When I am trying to install, getting the error:
Package is invalid. Details: 'Could not load extension icon 'images/icon_150.png'.'.

either the  extension icon path or extension icon is missing.

Comment: You can report your query from your Chrome Developer DashBoard Account.

Comment: @Vishal - Thanks for actually taking the time to try and download the extension. It works when I unpack it locally. And I see the file is there, that's weird it couldn't find the relative link to the image or that it would break the extension. So you're not able to install it at all?

Comment: hey buddy, found the error:
actually you have used the image icon "icon_150.png" in popup.html with src "images/icon_150.png", but in image folder there is no image with name "icon_150.png. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @Vishal - Thank you vishal! I really appreciated it. After that first comment I did a new update to the extension and fixed it. turns out images can't be in file paths, the icons must be in the root. :) Thanks again!

Comment: That's good.Well,  used path **src="Images/128-logo.png"** and it is working properly. just capitalized the *Images* instead of  **images**, check the output here [Google](http://nimb.ws/oCEHxq)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error was that in the Manifest, extension icons must be in root, and not relative paths.

Comment: The icon can be anywhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm thats right, my issue was I was referencing an "Image" folder but my link was "image/icon." So it turns out its case sensitive. I was just having trouble debugging since on my chrome development page, it was working fine and still able to find the image.